# Unable to add unallocated space to Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I removed 36gb out of my Windows partition with the intent of adding it to my Ubuntu one using GParted, but it's not working.

[GParted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBYux.png)

As the image shows, I have my Windows partition(sd3), next the unallocated space, and then the Ubuntu one. According to all solutions I've found so far, I'd just need to resize sd5(Ubuntu) to absorb the free space, but as the next image shows, I don`t have such an option.

[Trying to resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAQju.png)

I can't move it or make it bigger. I thought about turning the unallocated space into a partition itself, but I'm already at the max of 4 partitions.

I'm running GParted on a USB through 'Try Ubuntu'

Comment: Try expanding ``/dev/sda4``, the extended partition, into the free space first.  After that completes, you can expand ``/dev/sda5``.